# winrt::Windows::Media::Playback::MediaPlayer causing crash upon calling CopyFrameToVideoSurface

Tags: c++, windows, uwp, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I want to extract raw frames or bitmaps from a video that I'm playing in my C++ console application using C++/WinRT APIs. I'm simply using `CopyFrameToVideoSurface` to copy the video's frame to a `IDirect3DSurface`. But, it just crashes my program (which works fine, if I don't set up this frame extracting callback). My goal is to render this frame buffer somewhere else to display the video.

**Frame extracting code**
(see complete project here: https://github.com/harmonoid/libwinmedia/tree/stackoverflow)

```cpp
IDirect3DSurface surface = IDirect3DSurface();
Streams::IBuffer buffer = Streams::IBuffer();


DLLEXPORT void PlayerSetFrameEventHandler(
    int32_t player_id, void (*callback)(uint8_t* buffer, int32_t size,
                                        int32_t width, int32_t height)) {
  g_media_players.at(player_id).IsVideoFrameServerEnabled(true);
  g_media_players.at(player_id)
      .VideoFrameAvailable([=](auto, const auto& args) -> void {
        g_media_players.at(player_id).CopyFrameToVideoSurface(surface);
        SoftwareBitmap bitmap =
            SoftwareBitmap::CreateCopyFromSurfaceAsync(surface).get();
        bitmap.CopyToBuffer(buffer);
        (*callback)(buffer.data(), buffer.Length(), bitmap.PixelWidth(),
                    bitmap.PixelHeight());
      });
}
```

You may simply build this shared library using `cmake --build .`

For testing the crash, you can compile following example (also present on the link repo):
https://github.com/harmonoid/libwinmedia/blob/stackoverflow/examples/frame_extractor.cpp

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include "../include/internal.hpp"
int32_t main() {
  using namespace Internal;
  // Create a list of medias.
  const char* media_uris[] = {
      "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/"
      "ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4"};
  const int media_ids[] = {0};
  // Create a player instance.
  PlayerCreate(0);
  // Set frame callback (comment out the code to prevent crash from happening).
  PlayerSetFrameEventHandler(
      0, [](uint8_t*, int32_t, int32_t width, int32_t height) {
        printf("Video width: %d, Video height: %d.", width, height);
      });
  // Open list of medias.
  PlayerOpen(0, 1, media_uris, media_ids);
  // Start playing the player.
  PlayerPlay(0);
  // Prevent console from closing.
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

I will be really helped, if I can get help to fix the code or any other working method for extracting the frames or video bitmaps using `winrt::Windows::Media::Playback::MediaPlayer`.

Thankyou .

Following is the stacktrace of the crash:
[image: crash]

Comment: You are copying to a null surface `surface`. You can see in the Locals window that `destination` is null. Notice that you never created a surface or a buffer.

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks a lot for your reply. I understand that creating instance of raw `IBuffer` is possibly wrong, but how should I get a `IDirect3DSurface` (or something that implements `IDirect3DSurface`) in a console C++/WinRT app. Thankyou.

Comment: Hopefully there are some Direct3D tutorials that show how to create an IDirect3D11Surface. If you have an IDXGISurface, you can convert it to an IDirect3D11Surface via [CreateDirect3D11SurfaceFromDXGISurface](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sdk-api/blob/docs/sdk-api-src/content/windows.graphics.directx.direct3d11.interop/nf-windows-graphics-directx-direct3d11-interop-createdirect3d11surfacefromdxgisurface.md)

Comment: @RaymondChen thankyou very much, I will have a look.

Comment: An example of how to create an object that implements the `IDirect3DSurface` interface can be found at [Use MediaPlayer in frame server mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer#use-mediaplayer-in-frame-server-mode). Depending on your particular use case you might want to implement a different solution.

Comment: @IInspectable for your kind information, `CanvasDevice` is not available in C++/WinRT but Win2D (which requires separate projection to be generated and I'm already new to this in general).

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, you can add a reference to the [Win2D.uwp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Win2D.uwp/) or [Microsoft.Graphics.Win2D](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graphics.Win2D) NuGet packages, and the C++/WinRT projection is done automatically for you.